# Переименовывание загружаемых картинок simple_html_dom

Tags: simple-html-dom, php, парсер

Здравствуйте, уважаемые знатоки.

Прошу вашей помощи.
Написал с помощью simple html dom небольшой парсер картинок.
Вытягиваю циклом от туда сами картинки и названия ссылок к ним.
С помощью функции substr названия ссылок укорачиваю до 13 символов.
Сохраняю картинки в папку images.
Мне же необходимо название картинок изменить на названия укороченных ссылок.

Вот сам код:
    include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

```
$html = file_get_html('http://site.ru/items/search?utf8=');

// Find all links
foreach($html->find('div.item_text a') as $element) {
    $a = $element->href;
    $link = explode("/", $a);
    $url = end($link);

    echo substr($url, 0, 13). '<br />';
}

// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('div.item_img img') as $element) {
    echo '<img src="'.$element->src.'">' . '<br />';

    $src = $element->src;
    $arr = explode("/", $src);
    $name = end($arr);
    file_put_contents("images/$name", file_get_contents($src));
}
```

Очень жду вашей помощи или подсказки.

**Добавлено:**

Первый цикл выдает названия укороченных ссылок:

```
4602547000701
4602547000015
4601728012885
```

Второй цикл выдает сами изображения:

```
<img src="http://site.ru/system/images/tovar/small/151f938d3d16fea22f0dc7f73350e8ae.jpeg">
<img src="http://site.ru/system/images/tovar/small/1a610cb1bfecc513f5cc86c8898567b3.jpeg">
<img src="http://site.ru/noimage.gif">
```

Мне же необходимо переименовать названия картинок в название ссылок.
T. е. на примере первого изображения:
Было название изображения - `151f938d3d16fea22f0dc7f73350e8ae.jpeg`, стало `4602547000701.jpeg`

Comment: На что изменять? Пример можно, вход и выход желательно.

Comment: Вот он способ:-)
<code>
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://site.ru/items/search?utf8=');

// Find all links
foreach($html->find('div.item_text a') as $element) {
    $a = $element->href;
    $link = explode("/", $a);
    $url = end($link);

    echo substr($url, 0, 13). '
';
}

// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('div.item_img img') as $element) {
    echo '<img src="'.$element->src.'">' . '
';

    $src = $element->src;
    $arr = explode("/", $src);
    $name = end($arr);
    file_put_contents("images/$name", file_get_contents($src));
}
</code>